# How to approximate using the differential?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm working a practice problem for Calculus 3, and I'm given an equation to find the differential of: $z=3x^2+2y$ at the point $f(1,2)$

I've found the differential: $dz=6dx+2dy$

Next I'm supposed to use the differential to approximate $f(1.2,2.2)$, but I'm really not sure where to go this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
dz=6xdx+2dy
$$
which, at $(1,2)$, gives $6dx+2dy$.

Linear approximation (ie approximating the graph of the function near $x_0$ by the tangent at $x_0$) for the function $f(x,y)=3x^2+2y$ at $x_0$:
$$
f(x_0+h)\simeq f(x_0)+df_{x_0}(h).
$$

In your case, you set
$$
x_0:=(1,2)\qquad h:=(.2,.2)
$$
so that
$$
f(1.2,2.2)\simeq f(1,2)+df_{(1,2)}(.2,.2)=f(1,2)+6\cdot (.2)+2\cdot(.2)
$$
$$
=7+1.2+.4=8.6.
$$

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that the differential was at a specific point, added it to the OP.  Either way, for the dx portion of that, shouldn't the derivative of 3x^2 be 6x and not 3x as you have it?

Comment: @PseudoPsyche Yes, of course, typo, edited.

Comment: Ah, okay, this makes so much more sense now!  That was a way more straight forward explanation than in class!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go by the meaning of the derivative. It means when you change the parameters by a small amount, the value changes linearly as a function of this change. ie,

$$f(x+\Delta x) \approx f(x) + df(x).x$$

If you have a multivariable function then $x$ is a column vector, $df(x)$ is a row vector.

In your case you have  $dx=.2$, $dy=.2$ and

$$df(1,2) = \bigg[\frac{\partial}{dx}\bigg|_{(1,2)} f, \frac{\partial}{dy}\bigg|_{(1,2)}f\bigg]$$

$$\Bigg[\begin{array}{c}x  \\ y \end{array}\Bigg]=\Bigg[\begin{array}{c}1  \\ 2 \end{array}\Bigg]$$

I think you can compute now.